# Does Phonegap allow to make POST requests?

Tags: html, cordova, post

I'm working in an app with Phonegap. I did many GET requests for getting JSON files and they work nicely, but when I try to do the same but with a POST request, I have no callback and in the server I get error 400 (I don't even send anything to the server).

So I minimized my app and I included this in a plain HTML:

```
<form action="https://edge.suitepad.de:442/api/v1/8b17ec5acab7537b/orders/a4054d5fe4184431f55aca69cca9a7ef/purchase" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="order" value='{"currency":"eur","order_items":[{"id":265,"quantity":5}]}' />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Does this work for you? Do you receive any callback having this form in an app with Phonegap?

Thank you.

Comment: If I do exactly the same in a HTML, loading Phonegap, but in a browser, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post requests work just fine from phonegap - the bad request error is something specific to your combination of data and server setup.

The html you show certainly won't fire a callback though - as soon as you click submit, it is loading a page from the server and the phonegap page containing the callback is gone.